# Automated SQL Server slow query report?

Tags: sql-server

I am a developer and performance tester but not a DBA.  My team is working on a performance testing tool that is specific to our software.  One of the features we want it to have is the ability to generate a database report immediately after the test.  Our software is database agnostic.  For Oracle, I can easily create a snapshot id before and after the test and programmatically create an AWR report for those snapshots, write to a file and save with other artifacts we gather.  Works great.

For SQL Server, however, there is no AWR equivalent (that I know of).  I know the MDW as part of the SSMS has a UI for getting things like top 10 slow SQL and things like that.  But, I have not yet found a way to programmatically create and extract a SQL performance report (preferably similar to Oracle's AWR) for SQL Server.

I am even willing to create the report myself if I can find a way to extract the raw data.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated because searching online is not getting me anywhere.

P.S. I'm trying to do this in Java, by the way, but will accept help in any language.  Thanks again!

Comment: What is an AWR report? I can't even spell oracle let alone have any kind of knowledge of it. What does it show you?

Comment: Seems there are quite few ideas here. https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+awr+report&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Basically, I am trying to get a report that tells me the worst performing SQL by elapsed time.  Having it by cpu, io, etc would be good, too.  Basically, a report that tells me if I have poor performing SQL for a particular timeframe.  But the key is, I need it to be exported to a file automatically.  The links you sent, unless I'm missing something, I don't see the automated aspect of it - I need to be able to kick off a test and have a file with the info generated by my program.

Answer (score 1):

Good news! In SQL Server 2016, you can use [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store). This is like your flight recorder blackbox.. finding long running queries and waits. Capture baseline built in to SQL Server. You can compare before and after hardware changes and/or upgrades on queries. Maybe this similar to Oracle AWR.

Only available SQL Server 2016 and up.